# Adding a bulk number of users to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, multiple-users

To create a new user in Jenkins, admin needs to provide a username, emialID and password. Being an admin, is there a way to add a large number of users to Jenkins at a time by providing their username as their mail id, display name as their name and a common password*? 
*Assuming that password will be reset at the time of each user logging in

Answer (score 2):

I am using the below groovy script to add a user to Jenkins and provide only build permission.

```
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.tasks.Mailer

def userId = args[0]
def password = args[1]
def email = args[2]
def fullName= args[3]
def instance = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
def existingUser = instance.securityRealm.allUsers.find {it.id == userId}

if (existingUser == null) {
    def user = instance.securityRealm.createAccount(userId, password)
    user.addProperty(new Mailer.UserProperty(email));
    user.setFullName(fullName)

    def strategy = (GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy) 
    instance.getAuthorizationStrategy()
    strategy.add(hudson.model.Item.BUILD,userId)
    instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
    instance.save()
}
```

The script is invoked using jenkins-cli.

Comment: This is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to connect Jenkins to LDAP. See this plugin [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LDAP+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

looks like the Jenkins cli doesn't support add users , but check this one - using groovy script you can do it.

[Creating user in Jenkins via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716242/creating-user-in-jenkins-via-api)

if you want give specific permissions per job , maybe you can use the CLI **get-job** & **update-job** commands.

Or you can try check this one - [Jenkins Add permissions to jobs using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449432/jenkins-add-permissions-to-jobs-using-groovy) it discuses almost the same ...

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mor Lajb. 
Adding users is fine.Is there a way to set permissions for each user/group at job level using this groovy scripting?